# Android and Alarms in Background

Tags: android

How can i call the Background by multiple alarms every Hour and every 30 minutes , and for example how can I cancel only  the alarm (30 minutes) and the other one stays (1 Hour)

Comment: Set [Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) one for 1 hour and other one calculate the previous time + 30 minutes. Store the request code which you will use later for cancelling alarms.

Comment: Thanks, I try it